# How to take the most newest part of all reports and merge into one main report?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**EDIT**: I have found out that mongo does not allow to use special characters such as dots and the dollar sign as a key in the report so I had to rechange the structure of the JSON a bit. But, my question remains the same (I removed the old stuff so it will be more readable but you can still see it in the edit history section). The new structure looks as follows:

```
{                                                      
    "name": "test1",                                                            
    "main": [                                         
        {                                              
            "subs": [                                  
                {                                      
                    "data": [          
                        {                              
                            "group": "ABC",            
                            "values": [              
                                "tcsh"                 
                            ]                          
                        },                             
                        {                              
                            "group": "AA",            
                            "values": [              
                                "6.13.00"              
                            ]                          
                        }                              
                    ]                                  
                },                                     
                {                                      
                    "data": [          
                        {                              
                            "group": "xyz",            
                            "values": [              
                                "tcsh"                 
                            ]                          
                        },                             
                        {                              
                            "group": "SADA",            
                            "values": [              
                                "6.13.00"              
                            ]                          
                        }                              
                    ]                                  
                }
            ],
            "main_name": "MAIN",
            "main_path": "play_ground/MAIN"
        },
        {
            "subs": [
                {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "group": "BAB",
                            "values": [
                                "tcsh"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "group": "GO",
                            "values": [
                                "6.13.00"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "main_name": "MAIN2",
            "main_path": "play_ground/MAIN2"
        }
    ],
    "user": "easdasa",
    "timestamp": "1564437533"
}
```

I want to get all reports that have a name `test1` and a user `easdasa`. Then, I would like to take the latest block of `data` of each block of `subs`. This is done with the help of the timestamp.
For example in the following array I have two reports:

```
    [{                                                      
        "name": "test1",                                                            
        "main": [                                         
            {                                              
                "subs": [                                                                      
                    {                                      
                        "data": [          
                            {                              
                                "group": "xyz",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "tcsh"                 
                                ]                          
                            },                             
                            {                              
                                "group": "SADA",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "6.13.00"              
                                ]                          
                            }                              
                        ]                                  
                    }
                ],
                "main_name": "MAIN",
                "main_path": "play_ground/MAIN"
            }
        ],
        "timestamp": "1564437533"
    },
        {                                                      
        "name": "test1",                                                            
        "main": [                                         
            {                                              
                "subs": [                                  
                    {                                      
                        "data": [          
                            {                              
                                "group": "ABC",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "tcsh"                 
                                ]                          
                            },                             
                            {                              
                                "group": "AA",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "6.13.00"              
                                ]                          
                            }                              
                        ]                                  
                    },                                     
                    {                                      
                        "data": [          
                            {                              
                                "group": "xyz",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "tcsh"                 
                                ]                          
                            },                             
                            {                              
                                "group": "SADA",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "5.0.1",
                                    "12312"              
                                ]                          
                            }                              
                        ]                                  
                    }
                ],
                "main_name": "MAIN",
                "main_path": "play_ground/MAIN"
            }
        ],
        "timestamp": "1564437522"
    }]
```

The first report is was created after the second report (due to the timestamp). I can see that there is a block that located in the second report but not in the first report:

```
{                                      
    "data": [          
        {                              
            "group": "ABC",            
            "values": [              
                "tcsh"                 
            ]                          
        },                             
        {                              
            "group": "AA",            
            "values": [              
                "6.13.00"              
            ]                          
        }                              
    ]                                  
},
```

So I want the final report to heve it (besides all the blocks from the first report). Also, you can see that the values of the `SADA` group are diffrenet. So we want to take the first's report block. The final report should be:

```
    {                                                      
        "name": "test1",                                                            
        "main": [                                         
            {                                              
                "subs": [
                    {                                      
                        "data": [          
                            {                              
                                "group": "ABC",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "tcsh"                 
                                ]                          
                            },                             
                            {                              
                                "group": "AA",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "6.13.00"              
                                ]                          
                            }                              
                        ]                                  
                    },                  
                    {                                      
                        "data": [          
                            {                              
                                "group": "xyz",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "tcsh"                 
                                ]                          
                            },                             
                            {                              
                                "group": "SADA",            
                                "values": [              
                                    "6.13.00"              
                                ]                          
                            }                              
                        ]                                  
                    }
                ],
                "main_name": "MAIN",
                "main_path": "play_ground/MAIN"
            }
        ],
        "timestamp": "1564437533"
    }
```

In other words, in the (json) values of the `data` level I want to get the latest report and in the (json) values of the `subs` level I want to get all existing subs. So it will be more clear, in the (json) values of the `data` level I want to get all the groups and values of the latest report and for the (json) values of the `subs` level I want to have all the subs.

If I could specify steps:

- Get all reports by `user` and `name`.
- Theoritcly merge all report into one main report (the implmenetation could be diffrent). The merge will use be done by `main_name`.
- Remove all old `subs` values by `timestamp` that already exists in the latest report so the final report will have in the `subs` level only the newest objects and object from the old reports that were not in the newer reports.

Which query I should be in order to get the wanted report?

Comment: what do you mean by iterating ? Is it in you code or thru using any operators in mongoDB?

Comment: @srinivasy thanks for the reply. I would like to create a query which uses the mongoDB operators such as projection.

Comment: Okay as we've got the latest one, Can you provide how you data looks like when you say iterating thru each one do we need to group on something? also when you say project i.e; aggregation is only meant for querying, we can use $out though I wouldn't suggest as it's destructive, maybe if you want to purge data then you need to get it and do a bulk write, So far please test the below query and let me know..

Answer (score -2):

Please use the below query and check on stats, I can really say performance can be improved by having proper indexing as per your requirements(querying), Please use `$explain` ([enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/))
to check on query performance. I've considered your array exists in a field with key as **values** , Please let me know if this works or if it doesn't provide sample data, we can check on that:

```
db.getCollection('yourcollection').aggregate([{$unwind: '$values'},{$match : {'values.name': 'test1', 'values.user': 'galih'}},
{$sort: {'values.timestamp' : -1}},
{$limit: 1}
])
```

Comment: I don't think it does what I need. It should go to each block `data` of each block of `subs` and take the latest most updated by timestamp. link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/IO_7YYpHwD5

Comment: @vesii : Can you share sample of your entire document, So even if one object matches in the array it would bring the complete document out(I've considered values as key for that array), So this timestamp is not on sub level or main level it's on individual object level in that array, So first we get the latest object from that array and next do we need to merge subs from one previous one if it's not there in the latest ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be achieved that easy thru mongoDB, maybe you could get all the records with the same query and group by _id and then do it in your code. Also how deep do you need that, just the last one and one prior to that ?  Can you check my edit.